# Exception when arranging worksheets

Tags: c#, excel

I am getting this exception : `Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC`

It occurs on the line `sheet.Move(After: wb.Worksheets.Count);`

```
List<String> spreadsheets = new List<String>();
//spreadsheets is filled with names

while (spreadsheets.Count > i)
{
    Excel.Worksheet sheet = wb.Worksheets.Add();
    sheet.Name = spreadsheets[i];
    sheet.Move(After: wb.Worksheets.Count);
    i++;
}
```

Not quite sure the reasoning behind this error so any help is greatly appreciated!

It will also probably help if you know what I am trying to do...
Essentially just create a new worksheet, name it, and move it to the end of the other worksheets.

Comment: Check if `i` starts from `0`, Excel ranges starts from index `1`. Just give it a shot and see.

Comment: `spreadsheets` is an array of strings I created with names of sheets

Comment: @Habib I initially set `i` equal to `0` and it gets incremented if things are added to the list. I never use `i` in respect to Excel. I have read that this error tends to occur because excel is non-zero based

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.move.aspx):

> After
>
> Type: System.Object
>
> The sheet after which the moved sheet will
>   be placed. You cannot specify After if you specify Before.

You are passing an integer where it's looking for a worksheet.

Something like this might work:

```
sheet.Move(After: wb.Worksheets[wb.Worksheets.Count]);
```

Comment: You are all over this today! It's great! Thanks. I got another question coming up for you :)